# what triggers ping in redis while monitor command runs

Tags: redis, spring-data-redis, health-monitoring, health-check

[image]

I see ping returns while running monitor command in redis cli. They appear once in a 5 seconds. It seems a health check but there is no any configuration in my codes. Can it be related to spring actuator although I've already made below arrangement?

```
management:
  server:
    port: 9081
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: '*'
  health:
    elasticsearch:
      enabled: false
    redis:
      enabled: false
    probes:
      enabled: true
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess there are two possible choices here. One is as your mention it is probably some kinds of health check mechanism. My second guess is some kind of keep alive logic on your redis libary maybe this redis libary have a keep alive connection options for that?

Answer (score 0):

As @Faith mentioned, probably you have set up a liveness probe or something that checks regularly whether redis is alive or not by pinging it. For me the reason was a kubernetes livenessProbe and readinessProbe, both set up to ping each 10 seconds.